# Detect Contact After Changing contactTestBitMask in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, collision

I'm currently creating a 2D game in Swift using SpriteKit and I'm having a problem with the collision detection.

Let's say I have SKSpriteNode Foo in the game. Then let's say SKSpriteNode Bar spawns on top of Foo, but does NOT have the contactTestBitMask to trigger a contact. Then after a short moment (let's say 1 second) Bar changes its contactTestBitMask to detect contact with Foo.

Currently, Foo will have to actually move around a little bit OR move out from under Bar and return back to it to detect contact with it. I need Bar to immediately trigger contact with Foo when it changes its contactTestBitMask.

Maybe there's a different way to do this without changing the contactTestBitMask?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a physics body object intersecting another physics body object, no collision will register. It has something to do with the way SK registers a collision through movement only.

You have the option of using `intersectsNode:` when creating your object to see if it intersects another object and handle any subsequent code accordingly.

Comment: @lespommes - Happens to all the time.

Comment: Hey sangony, that worked unless I have a SKPhysicsBody that is created to outline a texture and not include alpha in the image. If that's the case, the node's actual frame is much larger than its physical body, so it is detecting an intersect even though it shouldn't (because it uses frames not physicsbodies).  Have any ideas?